# Changing ownership of filebeat installtion from root

Tags: linux, redhat, filebeat

I installed filebeat as root in my RedHat. We did using yum install filebeat-version.rpm. Now what happened is,  when install, we did it as root user. I believe there is security risk by installing as root user. Should i uninstall the filebeat and install as tar or is there a way to change its ownership. Please advice which path should be changed. as i know for now we have

```
/etc/filebeat 
/usr/share/filebeat
/var/lib/filebeat
```

What needs to be done. any other path i need  to modify.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: How you install it probably doesn't matter, what matters is which user runs it.

Comment: sure i will post there ya. so i need change the ownership?. what are the places involved ya